# How to apply withStyles material-ui in IE9?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, internet-explorer-9

I should apply material-ui in IE 9 (I hate to do... )
It works fine in Chrome and IE 11 but I got some errors which is look like from `withStyles`.
Is anyone success to solve the problem?

Working on react 16

1. Installed some of `babel-loader` and `polyfill`

In **packages.json**

```
@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3

@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2

babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0

es6-promise": "^4.2.6

fetch-ie8": "^1.5.0
```

2. Included CDN in **public/index.html**

=> `cdn.polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.js`

3. Imported these

> es6-object-assign/auto
>
> es6-promise/auto

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';

const styles = (theme) => ({
    test : {
        color: 'red'
    }
})

class Login extends Component{
    render(){

        const {classes} = this.props;

        return(
            <div>
                <AppBar>test</AppBar>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Login);
```

Chrome, IE11 works fine but IE10, IE9 brings error with blank page

Comment: any errors in your web console?

Comment: As you can see the [Supported Platforms](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/supported-platforms/#browser) in the material-ui documentation, it does not support versions of IE lower than 11.

Comment: Any success on this? Trying to make material-ui work with IE10...